# Why is the gloss not showing when i render the image?

Tags: rendering

I am following the Blender Guru donut tutorial and i use viewport shading so i can see the supposed rendering result.
[image]
It clearly shows gloss on the icing, but when i click 'render the image' the gloss is no longer there.
[image]
I tried to increase the power on the lamp but it didn't do anything to the gloss.
I also tried to swith my render engines from eevee to cycles but it didn't do anything either. Please tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured it out. In the material roughness there was a button "animate property" and it wasn't clicked. Now it's on and the model is rendering correctly.[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.